# DAX - Sum Workdays By Month within Range

Tags: business-intelligence, powerpivot, dax

I've been at this one a while.

**Objective:**  Pivot a monthly summary of days worked by *Resource* within the range for that *Resource* line where those dates (from *StartDate* to *EndDate*) correspond to the Dates table *IsWorkday* field.

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you define what a workday is. I suspect this is Monday thru Friday? If so, try the weekday function.

```
=WEEKDAY(serial_number,2)
```

Where serial_number is the cell with a date you want to identify. This would not exclude holidays, I would recommend an index/match on some holiday reference table for that.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/WEEKDAY-function-60e44483-2ed1-439f-8bd0-e404c190949a

Comment: Just noticed that you want the sum. For that you would NETWORKDAYS.

Comment: =NETWORKDAYS(A2,A3)

Where A2 is the first day in the month and A3 is the last day of the month.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NETWORKDAYS-function-48e717bf-a7a3-495f-969e-5005e3eb18e7